# Can't get the Java Hadoop libraries to work in the Intellij

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-14

I did successfully install the Intellij, was able to run simple Java code; however when referencing the Hadoop libraries from the Hadoop share folder, I can't seem to be able to import/reference the Hadoop libraries in the code

Can someone help import the Hadoop libraries properly?[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: Thank you, this is the very topic I followed and was able to import the Hadoop libraries as it is shown on a screenshot

But when trying to call those libraries in the code, the compilation fails